# How to remove "Java Search" entry from Search Group Icon in Eclipse PDE using Activities?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am aware that activities can be a powerful extension point to filter UI Contributions. I need to customize my product with minimal search entries in the Group Search Icon.

I've used

```
<activityPatternBinding activityId="com.myapp.myactivity"
        pattern="org.eclipse.mylyn.*"/>
```

to remove Remote, Task and Plug-in Search as I don't need them. I also need to remove the Java Search Entry , I've tried but in vain with the following

```
<activityPatternBinding activityId="com.myapp.myactivity"
    pattern="org\.eclipse\.jdt\.ui/org\.eclipse\.jdt\.ui\.JavaSearchPage"/>
```

I don't know where I am going wrong with this pattern, or is it possible at all to leverage Activities to achieve my purpose ?

Any guidance to the above will be really appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Try the expression `org\.eclipse\.jdt\.ui\.JavaSearchPage`

I'm not sure what you mean by 'Group Search icon'.  However, if you turn off the jdt capability from the preference page, all java search options from the main search menu and the tabs on the search dialog are removed.